# Storing JS/CSS/HTML for a sub-site

Tags: javascript, css

I am building out a Single Page Application using knockout.js on a sub-site which I do have control of the parent site collection.  I know most people recommend storing JS and CSS files in the Style Library but logically I find it odd if I were to store JS, CSS and HTML which are specific to a single page on a sub-site in the site collection Style Library.

So right now I have CSS, JS, IMAGE and HTML folders in the Site Assets library of the sub-site.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are "best practice" of doing it, but it really comes down to scope. If the files work where you have them and they can be correctly deployed there, I would say let them stay there.

It is really all about getting files into the right scope onto the server.

Now if this application is shared on multiple sub-sites, definitely move the files to a shared location.

Comment: Thanks.  I am going a 'split' route basically.  All of the libraries I am using (knockout, jQuery etc.) are getting dropped into the Style Library.  But the code which is SPECIFIC to that page and that page only (since it is MVVM) I am keeping in the local library.  I think it will actually help me manage in the long run.

Comment: That would be the right way to go. In the answer I referring more to the css and js files.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer if it solved your issue